# Why is it not practical to show progress for SQL statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a large dataset and some statements take anywhere from 30-70 min to execute, it's been a frustrating month!

I'm just wondering... is there a solid reason that SQL implementations don't generally report progress on a single execution plan? Or is it just that it's not important enough for most people?

Please englighten me.

Comment: I believe you should refactor such a query rather than observing progressbar for a while

Answer (score 5):

Most operations in SQL are meant to execute in a set-based fashion, logically as a single step. So there is no progress to report other than the result itself.

Actual SQL implementations, by necessity, require multiple execution steps to accomplish the single logical step; however any given SQL engine may change its approach from execution to execution (based on data volume, indexing, parallelism, etc.), so reporting progress would likely be unreliable and/or misleading

Comment: I would also add here that if the progress is very important to you, then you can easily implement a 'progress' table that you insert into during various stages of that sproc. I have done this many times, and I get the 100% desired effect you are looking for. You will simply then read the status/progress from this table. Almost like placing Print statements for debugging in the proc.

Answer (score 3):

because knowing how much work is left requires knowing in advance how much work needs to be done, which means you'd have had to run the query already previously.

Since underlying datasets can change, caches can be under differen levels of pressure, etc... the time required for one run of a query can have very little (or none at all) relationship to how much time it'll require the next time.

At best you can do a guesstimate, and end up with "4 hours of 30 minutes remaining" because things suddenly got a lot slower than the estimate allowed for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main reason is simply that there isn't much call for it. It wouldn't be that much work to provide a lousy progress indicator that might be accurate in some cases. But providing a progress indicator that's actually reliable is an awful lot of work and close to impossible in some cases.

For example, suppose a query required finding all the records that meet a certain set of criteria, and then going to another table to see if they pass some other criteria. To provide a useful progress indicator, you need to know how many records you're going to have to check in the other table. But you can't know that until you finish finding all the records.

You can naively just guess that each operation will take half the time. And this will provide a progress bar that gives forward motion and that reaches the end when the operation is complete. So it's not utterly useless. But the first half may drag on for hours and then second half complete instantly (if no matching records were found, for example). Or you might speed through the first half and then slow to a crawl at 50%.

So basically, any progress bar would just be there to convince you it hadn't given up.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you add progress indicators you are artificially slowing the processing down.  After all, it takes time for the program to stop what it's doing, increment some value, send that value back to the calling program etc.

For SQL queries this is usually a big no-no.  Especially in blocking situations in which the server might have other queries stacked up waiting to execute..

It sounds to me like you have one of two issues going on.  Either you have a highly unoptimized process or you have a server that is way too under powered to handle your processing.  I'd look into fixing one (or both) of those.  Usually it's the process that needs fixing.

Comment: I think it's the latter: we have a server that's really not suited for the task. Interestingly enough, it's dedicated solely to this and processing at most a handful of queries at any given time. In this scenario, it seems natural that you'd see progress, but I can certainly appreciate the complexities that come into play with high-volume production systems.